# Keep getting "Navigation was not found" error when trying to create a new migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a website with Visual Studio 2022.

I created a database and some models and they have corresponding tables in the database.

When I try to create a new migration I keep getting this error:

> Navigation 'MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users
> (Dictionary<string, object>).UserProgresses' was not found. Please add
> the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.

However, this navigation already exists in the model as well as in the DbContext:

```cpp
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto-generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models
{
    public partial class Users
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // This line configures it as an identity column
        public int UserIntId { get; set; } // New property for the user identifier

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }

        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

        public int ProgressPercentage { get; set; } // Percentage of the course completed

        public int BeginnerProgress { get; set; } // Percentage of the course completed

        public int IntermediateProgress { get; set; } // Percentage of the course completed

        public int AdvancedProgress { get; set; } // Percentage of the course completed

        public int RecordingProgress { get; set; } // Percentage of the course completed

        // Navigation property for UserProgress
        public ICollection<UserProgress> UserProgresses { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the DBContext:

```cpp
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProgress>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserProgress");
            entity.HasKey(up => up.UserProgressId);

            // Configure UserIntId and LessonId as foreign keys
            entity.HasOne(up => up.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserProgresses)  // Specify the navigation property
            .HasForeignKey(up => up.UserIntId)
            .IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(up => up.Lesson)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(up => up.LessonId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Configure other properties as needed
        });


        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Users");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.UserIntId);
            entity.Property(e => e.UserIntId).UseIdentityColumn(); // This line configures UserIntId as an identity column
            entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
            entity.Property(e => e.PasswordHash).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
            entity.Property(e => e.RegistrationDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
            entity.Property(e => e.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

         entity.HasMany(u => u.UserProgresses)  // Specify the navigation property
        .WithOne(up => up.User)  // Specify the inverse navigation property in UserProgress
        .HasForeignKey(up => up.UserIntId)
        .IsRequired();
        });
}
```

And this is the UserProgress model where the navigation leads to:

```cpp
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models
{
    public class UserProgress
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserProgressId { get; set; } // Primary key for UserProgress table

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        [Column("UserIntId")]
        public int UserIntId { get; set; } // Foreign key pointing to Users table

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Lesson")]
        [Column("LessonId")]
        public int LessonId { get; set; } // Foreign key pointing to Lesson table

        [Required]
        [Column("IsCompleted")]

        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; } // Flag indicating if the lesson is completed

        public Users User { get; set; } // Navigation property to User model

        public Lesson Lesson { get; set; } // Navigation property to Lesson model
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. Maybe the issue has something to do with the `ContextModelSnapshot` file? I tried to edit that a few times because I couldn't find any issues elsewhere.

Here is the snapshot file for good measure:

```cpp
// <auto-generated />
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models;

#nullable disable

namespace MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(MyFirstBlackMetalAlbumContext))]
    partial class MyFirstBlackMetalAlbumContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.11")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Comment", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("CommentId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Text")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("Timestamp")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<int>("UserId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasIndex("UserId");

                    b.ToTable("Comments");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Lesson", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("LessonId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("LessonId"));

                    b.Property<string>("Content")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("DifficultyLevel")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("Duration")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Title")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("LessonId");

                    b.ToTable("Lessons");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.UserCommentsViewModel", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<DateTime>("CreatedAt")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<int>("LessonId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<byte[]>("ProfilePicture")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("varbinary(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Text")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("UserName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("UserProgressId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    //   b.Property<int>("UsersUserIntId")
                    //     .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("UserIntId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasIndex("UserProgressId");

                    b.HasIndex("UserIntId");

                    b.ToTable((string)null);

                    b.ToView(null, (string)null);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.UserProgress", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("UserProgressId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("UserProgressId"));

                    b.Property<bool>("IsCompleted")
                        .HasColumnType("bit")
                        .HasColumnName("IsCompleted");

                    b.Property<int>("LessonId")
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasColumnName("LessonId");

                    b.Property<int>("UserIntId")
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasColumnName("UserIntId");

                    b.HasKey("UserProgressId");

                    b.HasIndex("LessonId");

                    b.HasIndex("UserIntId");

                    b.ToTable("UserProgress", (string)null);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("UserIntId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("AdvancedProgress")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("BeginnerProgress")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Email")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(100)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(100)");

                    b.Property<int>("IntermediateProgress")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("PasswordHash")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(128)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(128)");

                    b.Property<byte[]>("ProfileImage")
                        .HasColumnType("varbinary(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("ProgressPercentage")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int>("RecordingProgress")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("RegistrationDate")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime");

                    b.Property<string>("Username")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(50)
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)");

                    b.HasKey("UserIntId");

                    b.ToTable("Users", (string)null);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("UserComments", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("CommentId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("CommentId"));

                    b.Property<DateTime>("CreatedAt")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<int>("LessonId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Text")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("UserIntId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("UserName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("CommentId");

                    b.HasIndex("UserIntId");

                    b.ToTable("UserComment");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Comment", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", "User")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.UserCommentsViewModel", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.UserProgress", "UserProgress")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("UserProgressId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", "Users")
                        .WithMany()
                        //.HasForeignKey("UsersUserIntId")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserIntId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("UserProgress");

                    b.Navigation("Users");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.UserProgress", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Lesson", "Lesson")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("LessonId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", "User")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("UserIntId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                   // b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", null)
                     //   .WithMany("UserProgresses")
                      //  .HasForeignKey("UsersUserIntId");
                     // .HasForeignKey("UserIntId");

                    b.Navigation("Lesson");

                    b.Navigation("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.UserProgress", "UserProgress")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("UserIntId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("UserProgress");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("UserComments", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", "User")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("UserIntId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.Models.Users", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("UserProgresses");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Edited the Dbcontext to make the navigation property more explicit but that didn't help.

Edited the snapshot to do the same. Didn't help.

Comment: You should not edit snapshot files manually (at least in vast majority of cases).

Comment: Are you using database-first approach? Can you please post a [mre] somewhere (like github)?

Comment: Hello, I copied my project to this GitHub URL  https://github.com/sexypizza/MyfirstBlackMetalAlbum.com.git

Sorry, I'm still very new to this GitHub thing, I tried to delete extra scripts to keep it minimal but I cant commit the changes for some reason in visual studio. So this is the whole project for now. Its a small project though.

pretty sure I'm doing a code first approach.

Comment: It seems that your repo is private, make it public.

Comment: Hello, sorry about that, I made it public now.

Answer (score 0):

All good, I solved the issue by dropping the recreating the DB.

Comment: it's great that you have found your answer, but from my point of view, now you can delete your database and recreate it again, in production you can't, so be careful with your migrations and always watch out